# C++: ambiguous overload for 'operator='

Tags: c++11

I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE and whenever I try to build the file this code brings up an error:

```
    {
   cin >> input ;
    locale loc;
   for (string::size_type i=0; i<input.length(); ++i)
    input[i] = tolower(input[i],loc);}


    {
        if (input == "not")
            "" != "";

        else if (input == "and")
            "" && "";

        else if (input == "or")
            "" || "";

        else if (input == "yes")
            input = true;

        else if (input == "no")
            input = false;
    }
```

The error occurs where I try to make the word "no" equal to the Boolean operator false.
This brings up this error:

```
Projects\Samantha\main.cpp|40|error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'bool')|
```

Now I've tried searching for this problem but I haven't been able to find anything to help me. If someone could please help me to figure what the problem is and how I can fix it I would be very appreciative.

Comment: `input = "false";` note the quotation marks.

Comment: Note that your previous 3 ifs do nothing

Comment: @RetiredNinja I understand how that works. But I would like it to be equal to logical false. Is there anyway I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to assign a Boolean to a string.
You have two options here

- Create a bool variable where you will store your `false` value
- assign a string literal instead of a boolean `input = "false";`

Please note that the first three ifs are doing nothing since you are performing logical operations on empty string literals and not storing the result anywhere.

I'd also recommend to avoid using `if()` conditions without following braces since that is an error-prone, difficult to maintain and difficult to read approach.

```
else if (input == "yes")
    {
        booleanVariable = true;
    }
```